# Find the nth value in hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, hue

I am trying to identify the Nth Score Value which is also dependant on another variable.

For example I want to see the nth Transaction amount of each person, the issue I currently have is that my RANK does not re-start the count of n at each name, it just continues down the output like a row count:
Syntax example:

```
    SELECT name, txn_amount, dense_rank() over (order by name,txn_amount desc ) as nth_value FROM payment_table
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

P.S I am using HIVE to run this if it helps

Comment: you need to partition by name and order by txn_amount desc.

Comment: thank you vkp can you put this into the example to ensure I do this correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to *partition* by one value and *order* by the other:

```
SELECT name, txn_amount,
FROM (SELECT pt.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by name order by txn_amount desc ) as nth_value
      FROM payment_table pt
     ) pt
WHERE nth_value = X;
```

The subquery is needed to get a particular value.  If you want multiple values in the same row, you can use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN nth_value = 1 THEN txn_amount END) as value_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN nth_value = 2 THEN txn_amount END) as value_2
FROM (SELECT pt.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by name order by txn_amount desc ) as nth_value
      FROM payment_table pt
     ) pt
WHERE nth_value = X
GROUP BY name;
```

Note:  `DENSE_RANK()` will ignore duplicates.  If you want to see those as well (so the second value could have the same value as the first), then use `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: Gordon - thank you so much, this has resolved the issue and yes I was testing both outputs, row number and Dense rank. Very quick responses, very much apprecitaed